# Using different styles in Roboto Font

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-family

I added `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`  to my HTML page.

I've selected Normal 400 and Light 300 styles, but how do I use them in my CSS.

I've got this in my CSS:

```
body{
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

In my heading I want to use that Light 300, but how can I?

```
#heading
{
//what should go here

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the [`font-weight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) to it's appropriate value:

```
#heading {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: But, I'm using <h1> for my haeading and I'm getting a weird bold font.But, when I remove <h1> and increase fontsize by font-size : 200%, I'm achieving the result. But I think using <h1> for heading is advisable since browser distinguishes it. How can Iachieve the same by using <h1>.

Comment: The same way. Most browsers default stylishness will apply a bold weight to all fonts. You just need to override it.

Comment: How do I do that buddy, I tried but couldn't. How to remove that bold weight. I used font-weight : 300 but didn't work.

Comment: Stylesheets* and bold fonts *for headings* (was using mobile!) - http://jsfiddle.net/rqf7F/ works just fine for me on Firefox

Comment: Thanks @Ian Clark for your time.It worked for me as well.I included my heading in <p> and reomving it solved the issue.Thanks for ur time.